# wp_handle_upload error "Specified file failed upload test" but still creates attachment?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta, uploads

Having a bit of trouble with an image upload custom meta box. What happens is the uploaded image is created as an attachment but the wp_handle_upload seems to kick back the error "Specified file failed upload test" rather than updating my post meta? Seem odd though that the attachment is created without issues?

Heres the code:

```
// Make the forms multipart
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'post_edit_form_tag');
function post_edit_form_tag() {
   echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}

/* Setup custom meta boxes for posts */
$new_meta_boxes =
    array(
    "xxxx_kw1" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_kw1",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "Keyword 1",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_url1" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_url1",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "URL 1",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_kw2" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_kw2",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "Keyword 2",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_url2" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_url2",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "URL 2",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_kw3" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_kw3",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "Keyword 3",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_url3" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_url3",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "URL 3",
        "type" => "text"
        ),
    "xxxx_image" => array(
        "name" => "xxxx_image",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => "Image Upload",
        "type" => "file"
        )

);

function new_meta_boxes() { 
    global $post, $new_meta_boxes;

    foreach($new_meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        $meta_box_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_box['name'], true);

        if($meta_box['type'] == 'file') { $meta_box_value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'xxxx_attached_image', true); }

        if($meta_box_value == "")
        $meta_box_value = $meta_box['std']; 

        echo'<input type="hidden" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" id="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" value="'.wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ).'" />';

        echo'<p><label for="'.$meta_box['name'].'">'.$meta_box['title'].'</label></p>';

        echo'<input type="'.$meta_box['type'].'" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'" value="'.$meta_box_value.'" size="55" />';
    }
}

function create_meta_box() {
    global $theme_name;
    if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) {
        add_meta_box( 'new-meta-boxes', 'PR xxxx Paid Information', 'new_meta_boxes', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
    }
}

function save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $new_meta_boxes;

    $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

    foreach($new_meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        // Verify
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
            return $post_id;

        if($meta_box['type'] == 'file') : // if data is a file we'll need to treat if differently...

            $data = $_FILES[$meta_box['name']];

            // If the upload field has a file in it
            if(isset($data) && ($data['size'] > 0)) {

                // Get the type of the uploaded file. This is returned as "type/extension"
                $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($data['name']));
                $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

                // Set an array containing a list of acceptable formats
                $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

                // If the uploaded file is the right format
                if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {

                    // Options array for the wp_handle_upload function. 'test_upload' => false
                    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false ); 

                    // Handle the upload using WP's wp_handle_upload function. Takes the posted file and an options array
                    $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($data, $upload_overrides);

                    // If the wp_handle_upload call returned a local path for the image
                    if(isset($uploaded_file['file'])) {

                        // The wp_insert_attachment function needs the literal system path, which was passed back from wp_handle_upload
                        $location = $uploaded_file['file'];

                        // Generate a title for the image that'll be used in the media library
                        $file_title = $uploaded_file['file'];

                        // Set up options array to add this file as an attachment
                        $attachment = array(
                            'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file_type,
                            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_title)),
                            'post_content' => '',
                            'post_status' => 'inherit',
                            'post_parent' => $post_id,
                            'guid' => $uploaded_file['url']
                        );

                        // Run the wp_insert_attachment function. This adds the file to the media library and generates the thumbnails. If you wanted to attach this image to a post, you could pass the post id as a third param and it'd magically happen.
                        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $location, $post_id );
                        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $location );
                        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,  $attach_data);

                        // Before we update the post meta, trash any previously uploaded image for this post.
                        // You might not want this behavior, depending on how you're using the uploaded images.
                        $existing_uploaded_image = (int) get_post_meta($post_id,'xxxx_attached_image', true);
                        if(is_numeric($existing_uploaded_image)) {
                            wp_delete_attachment($existing_uploaded_image);
                        }

                        // Now, update the post meta to associate the new image with the post
                        update_post_meta($post_id,'xxxx_attached_image',$attach_id);

                        // Set the feedback flag to false, since the upload was successful
                        $upload_feedback = false;


                    } else { // wp_handle_upload returned some kind of error. the return does contain error details, so you can use it here if you want.

                        $upload_feedback = 'There was a problem with your upload: '.$uploaded_file['error'];
                        update_post_meta($post_id,'xxxx_attached_image',$attach_id);

                    }

                } else { // wrong file type

                    $upload_feedback = 'Please upload only image files (jpg, gif or png).';
                    update_post_meta($post_id,'xxxx_attached_image',$attach_id);

                }

            } else { // No file was passed

                $upload_feedback = false;

            }

            // Update the post meta with any feedback
            update_post_meta($post_id,'xxxx_attached_image_upload_feedback',$upload_feedback);

        else : // valid the input as normal

            $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name']];

            if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name']) == "")
                add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data, true);
            elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true))
                update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data);
            elseif($data == "")
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true));

        endif;

    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_meta_box');
add_action('save_post', 'save_postdata');
```

If anyone can help I'd send a virtual thumbs up and a beer! :-)

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) instead, solved a similar problem for me.